# Load previous pages on top of the page when "history.back" (click browser back button)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, html5-history

**The main achievement:**
Load previous pages when going back from the detail product page to category/shop archive.

**What I have done:**
I have a WordPress/WooCommerce website where I have implemented lazy loading over shop/category pages through AJAX. Also, once the next page is loaded, the application updates the browser's URL with the `pushState()` method.

**Case study:**
Imagine you visit `example.com/shop`, and you scroll down. When you reach the footer, the next page is lazy loaded through AJAX and the browser's URL updates to `example.com/shop/page/2`. Once on page number two, you click on a product (`example.com/product/lorem-ipsum`), read the details, and see the pictures. Then you decide to go back by clicking the browser's back button. In that scenario, now you are back to the page `example.com/shop/page/2`, but the problem is that page one does not load on top of page two, so only the products of page two are showing. Once on page number two, can I automatically load the previous page/pages above the current page?

**Real example:**
If you visit the [Nike website](https://www.nike.com/w/mens-running-shoes-37v7jznik1zy7ok), you will see what I would like to achieve on my website. Please, load multiple pages scrolling down. Once done, click on a product and go back by clicking the browser's back button. Once the page is loaded again, you will appear in the exact place where you were before visiting the detail page, and you will see how the previous pages have been loaded on top of the product that has the focus (just the one you clicked).

**What I have tried:**
I have searched over the internet, and I haven't found anything. Maybe I do not know what to search. I have read that the window `popstate` event is fired when you click the back/forward button. I have tried to use this event to run some tests, but I have failed. I'm lost :(

Can you help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if there's any wordpress plugin for that. As far I know, you have to play with the cache. For sure, [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) does that (as well as lot more usages) but no longer under active development. The new replacement is [hotwired/turbo](https://github.com/hotwired/turbo) I haven't tested this one yet. The idea is to store the current page state in cache and when you hit back, it hijack the request to return the page from the cache instead of re-requesting to the server.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to take a look. Thanks @ClémentBaconnier.